# send Touch to Parent View swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a View that serves as a parent to 3 subviews. The three subviews all filled the parent view. I added touch gesture to the parent view. My goal is to implement some function when a user selects the any of the child of the parent view. How do I pass touch event from the child to the parent.

I have tried adding touch gesture to each of the child view and delegating the touch to that of the parent, but it didn't work. What re my options thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code, this is very difficult to debug without seeing the implementation, the theory sounds ok

Answer (score 0):

At first specify unique tag to all 3 subviews you have under the parent view.

Secondly add a tap gesture like this in `viewDidLoad()` method of parent VC.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapEvent:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Now, recognize on which view touch has occurred or done:-

```
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
         UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
         // here you can get your touch
         NSLog(@"Touched view tag  %d",touch.view.tag );

       //by this you can differentiate on which view touch has been done.
    }
```